# My wordpress wp-admin is not opening??Please give your suggestions

Tags: wordpress

> Yesterday, I created a blog for my site ayurprakash.com. All I did was
>   installing another wordpress in the existing one and replacing the
>   domain with blog.ayurprakash.com. I made changes in the settings for
>   the site and wordpress url and changed the url to
>   www.ayurprakash.com/blog. I installed several plugins and altered some
>   code inside blog folder. But now, when I run the url
>   www.ayurprakash.com/blog/wp-admin.Nothing appears. I changed the url
>   to www.ayurprakash.com/blog/wp-login.php. the front panel is opening
>   asking for username and password. But when I clicked the submit
>   button, nothing is displayed except the text--"Blocked". What should I
>   do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn `WP_DEBUG` in wp-config to true (located on line 81) and after trying to log in it will direct to the offending piece of code. Then remove that code.